# procmon - how to set backing file size and customize it according to my needs?

Tags: procmon

I activates backing file and it creates new file one current reaches 383K.

I've tried to look all over the menu, tools didn't see place to configure that.

how can I set bigger files? don't want to come tomorrow and see thousands files in windows folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change this. Each file contains around a million events.